# CMake Conditional Library Linking Depending on the Platform

Tags: c++, cmake

I am linking Boost into my application using CMake:

I have this code that works on Linux in my `CMakeLists.txt`:
`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(app -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lcrypt)`

But on OpenBSD `-lboost_thread` is `-lboost_thread-mt` instead, and `-lcrypt` is not required. Is there a way of writing the CMakeLists.txt in such a way that it handles both of these cases depending on which library exists?

Comment: Try [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html) and the variables it exports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The need to handle such platform specific differences is why one should use find modules instead. Specifically [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) in this case. After `find_package` is executed, you should be able to pull in the thread library by its canonical target name `Boost::thread`.

Any required PUBLIC libraries or headers will be part of the the canonical target's link interface, and so will be added automatically, without further effort on your part. All you'll need to do is add the canonical target as a link dependency

```
target_link_libraries(app Boost::thread)
```